# Two input boxes for date, using those for fetching data from database

Tags: jsp

I have a database that stores the incoming letters according to date when it is received.
I want a JSP page that has 2 date input boxes first `FROM WHICH DATE`, second `TO WHICH DATE`.
That two dates can be selected and compared and data from database can be fetched between these two dates.
I know the query which is to applied.
I want two pop up calendars for the input boxes.

The procedure for comparing those dates to data base..in JSP AND HTML

```
FROM DATE {selection popup calender}      TO DATE{another calender}
```

And the code for storing these values in variables so that they can be used in the query.
I'm new to JSP kindly help

Comment: Popup calender you can use [jQuery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Answer (score 0):

Go through the below mentioned link you might find something productive over here.
They have used jquery in this.

http://hscripts.com/scripts/JavaScript/popup-calendar.php

In this, the input type is given as date field , you can get the Value easily for comparing with the values from the datatbase.
Hope this helps.